# Binding Listbox SelectedItems to a Slider in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, slider, converters

I am relatively new to WPF, but can you provide an example of how to bind a slider value to a selected item in a listbox. Ideally, as the user moves the slider, the onscreen item changes dynamically as the slider value changes. From reading, I understand that you need to use an attached property or value converter since we are binding different types of values. If so, can you provide a simple example of the most efficient method.

Thank you.

Comment: What? I don't understand, you want to bind the slider value to what?

Comment: As the slider control moves, the listbox item updates. I assume that the listbox item would be databinded to the slider value somehow. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this really is the question, but in case you mean to move the selected item through the ListBox items you could directly bind the `SelectedIndex` of the ListBox to the Slider `Value`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        ...
        <ListBoxItem>10</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <Slider Name="slider" Minimum="0" Maximum="9"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Of course you would have to adjust the Slider's `Maximum` value to the actual number of items minus one.